# Passenger Nginx Rails in debian 7 not working

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, debian-wheezy

I have installed Phusion passenger following official document :

https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu

Following Steps are performed:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

Added this:

```
deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger wheezy main
```

And then

```
sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
sudo apt-get update
```

sudo apt-get install nginx-extras passenger -y

copied path returned by `/usr/bin/passenger-config --root`
and appended `passenger_root` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
sudo service nginx restart
sudo gem install passenger
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module

sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx
sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults
```

Then restarted nginx.

I have my rails app in `/opt/www/app.co/app`(deployed using mina). And have added `app.co` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` with symbolic link in `sites-enabled`, and configured server block (/etc/nginx/sites-available/app.co) like:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    root /opt/www/app.co/app/public;
    passenger_enabled on;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

**/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf** looks like this:
>

> worker_processes 1;
>   events {
>        worker_connections 1024;
>   }
>
> http {
>       passenger_root /var/lib/gems/1.91./gems/passenger-4.0.53;
>       passenger_ruby /home/deployer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby;
>       include mime_types;
>       default_type application/octet-stream;
>       sendfile on;
>       keepalive-timeout 65;
>
> ```
> server {
>              listen 80;
>              server_name localhost;
>              root /opt/www/app.co/app/public;
>              passenger_enabled on; 
>       }
>   }
> ```

Inspite of these configurations, always default nginx page is loading

Have tried to edit nginx default page located in

`/opt/nginx/html/index.html 
/usr/share/nginx/www/index.html>`

But no difference, always default page.

**sudo passenger-status** shows:

> Version : 4.0.53 
>   Date    : 2014-12-11 04:43:20 -0600
>   Instance: 22618
>   ----------- General information -----------
>   Max pool size : 6
>   Processes     : 0
>   Requests in top-level queue : 0
>
> ----------- Application groups -----------

**sudo passenger-memory-stats** shows:

> ------------- Apache processes -------------
>   WARNING: The Apache executable cannot be found.
>   Please set the APXS2 environment variable to your 'apxs2' executable's filename, or set 
> the HTTPD environment variable to your 'httpd' or 'apache2' executable's filename.
>
> ---------- Nginx processes -----------
>   PID    PPID   VMSize    Private  Name
>   --------------------------------------
>   22618  1      112.0 MB  0.2 MB   nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
>   22620  22618  112.3 MB  0.5 MB   nginx: worker process
>   22621  22618  112.3 MB  0.5 MB   nginx: worker process
>   22623  22618  112.3 MB  0.5 MB   nginx: worker process
>   22624  22618  112.3 MB  0.5 MB   nginx: worker process
>   Processes: 5
>   Total private dirty RSS: 2.09 MB
>
> ----- Passenger processes -----
>   PID           VMSize        Private    Name
>   -------------------------------
>   22600  25.6 MB   0.3 MB   PassengerWatchdog
>   22603  109.3 MB  0.3 MB   PassengerHelperAgent
>   22612  145.0 MB  0.9 MB   PassengerLoggingAgent
>   Processes: 3
>   Total private dirty RSS: 1.54 MB

Stopped nginx with:
sudo service nginx stop

But still default page. Am i missing anything here ?!

Please lend me some inputs how to correct this issue and configure my rails app.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/editing-help. Also, the editing icons in the question box exist for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

The `root` should be pointed at your Rails app's `public` directory, not its `app` directory.

```
    root /opt/www/app.co/public;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention it, i am pointing it to public directory. I have updated my question.

Comment: Did you forget anything else? Now is the time to add it to your question.

Comment: Ah! no... Have included all things i have tried out. Still not working. Always default page. Wondering from where it is loading it?